# requestFileSystem does not work on android phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am working on a cordova based mobile application. I need to create a file on phone and save a blob into it. I tried using cordova file plugin as mentioned at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Before I could use any of the file system API, i need to requestfilesystem like below.

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
if (!window.requestFileSystem)
    alert("ERROR");
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024*5, gotFS, fail);
```

I have put the alert just for debugging. On android phone I get this alert. Hence I am unable to work with file system API.

is there any alternative way to use filesystem APIs on android phone ?
Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

The link in your question doesn't concern the phone file API.

You should use :

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail); 

/*Used for storage that should not be removed by the user agent without application 
or user permission.*/
```

or

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);

//Used for storage with no guarantee of persistence.
```

[Full example here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter)

Comment: It does not work. Gives me error "LocalFileSystem is not defined"

Comment: Have you added the File plugin ? with cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file. Look at the very beginning of the link in my answer to see if you have all the things set up to use the File plugin

Comment: Yes, I have added File plugin. My "cordova plugins ls" command returns "org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"". Also, I have following in android config.xml and androidmanifest.xml file respectively: <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>                                                                                        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I don't know then, the problem might come from the code, try the full example of the documentation... :/

Comment: Got it working finally. The issue was in my code only as i was not having deviceready eventlistener and because of this the file plugin was not getting loaded. Thanks BipBip for your pointers. It helped.